# What is the sum of this by telescopic method?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{r^3+(r^2+1)^2}{(r^4+r^2+1)(r^2+r)}$$

This is to be done by telescopic method. I've used many things like writing $r^4+r^2+1=(r^2+r+1)(r^2-r+1)$ but have failed. I think all it needs is the correct rearranging of terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Since $r^3+(r^2+1)^2=r(r^2+r)+(r^4+r^2+1)$,
  $$
  \frac{r^3+(r^2+1)^2}{(r^4+r^2+1)(r^2+r)}=\frac{r}{r^4+r^2+1}+\frac1{r^2+r}.
  $$
- Since $r^4+r^2+1=(r^2+r+1)(r^2-r+1)$,
  $$
  \frac{2r}{r^4+r^2+1}=a_r-a_{r+1},\qquad a_r=\frac{1}{r(r-1)+1}.
  $$
- Since $r^2+r=r(r+1)$,
  $$
  \frac1{r^2+r}=b_r-b_{r+1},\qquad b_r=\frac1r.
  $$

And now, grab your telescope!

Comment: In the second bullet, the second line, its r, not 2r.

Comment: But i understood what u meant. You  should have multiplied by 1/2 to state it clearly and thanks...i finally got my answer(its 3/2).

Comment: "You should have multiplied by 1/2 to state it clearly"... No. "i finally got my answer"... Good.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Rewrite $\,r^4+r^2+1=(r^2+1)^2-r^2$ and observe that $\,r^2\pm r+1=\left(r\pm\frac 12\right)^2+\frac 34$.

Comment: Sorry man, its useless here.

Comment: But good observation skills, @RaymondManzoni..