# Sum of a series to be attempted by telescopic method.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Ok now this one is pretty tough, my sir said that this couldn't be done by convention...
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{r^2-\frac12}{r^4+\frac14}\right)$$ 
Ok, so applying the same sense in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464417/what-is-the-sum-of-this-by-telescopic-method), I cannot go ahead. The denominator and the numerator don't match up to give me something. I believe it is interesting though. Help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By partial fraction decomposition we have
$$\frac{r^2-\frac{1}{2}}{r^4+\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{4r-2}{2r^2-2r-1}-\frac{4(r+1)-2}{2(r+1)^2-2(r+1)-1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(u_r-u_{r+1})$$
so by telescoping we have
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{r^2-\frac12}{r^4+\frac14}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=1}^n(u_r-u_{r+1})=\frac{1}{2}(u_1-u_{n+1})$$

Comment: How did you get to the second line?($4r-2...$)?

Comment: We factor $r^4+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}(2r^2-2r+1)(2r^2+2r+1)$ so the given fraction has the form $$\frac{ar+b}{2r^2-2r+1}+\frac{cr+d}{2r^2+2r+1}$$ and we determine $a,b,c$ and $d$.

Comment: Seems odd to have $1/2$ in the partial fraction, when it factors with $4r-2$ and $4r+2.$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}  r^4+\frac{1}{4}&=\left(r^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-r^2\\&= \left(r^2+\frac{1}{2}-r\right)\left(r^2+\frac{1}{2}+r\right)\\&=\left(r^2+\frac{1}{2}-r\right)\left[(r+1)^2+\frac{1}{2}-(r+1)\right]\end{align}$$

Comment: I think you did not get the point of giving the link. If I replace r by r+1 in $r^2-r + \frac12$, I get $ r^2 +r+\frac12$.Tell me something new...

Comment: @Rohinb97 All you need to do is partial fraction decomposition. Exactly like in the hint you provided, it becomes a telescopic sum. The key here is that the denominator factors, and replacing $r \to r+1$ in one of the factors yields the second. And of course, the numerators match, which can be seen from partial fraction decomposition.....

Answer (score 0):

In general, any rational function summation with a possibility of telescoping summation trick typically admits a partial fraction decomposition where you can express the decomposition of the $n$th term as a difference of a function $f(n) - f(n+1)$ or at least as $f(n) - f(n+k)$ for some integer $k \geq 1$ (although if $k > 1$ this makes the resulting formula you get from telescoping trick more complicated, but still possible to write down with $k$ cases)